# PhpStorm Laravel Dusk w/ a testing database

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

I currently have PhpStorm running Dusk Test successfully however, I would like it to use the testing database I have set up. Per other threads and resources online, I have created the .env.dusk.local and phpunit.dusk.xml that points to the testing database I have created. When I run the dusk tests in PhpStorm the application that is rendered in Chromium doesn't use the testing database that is described in these files but when I run them using php artisan dusk in the terminal it uses the correct databases.

It seems like I need make phpstorm aware of what env file to use when running the tests. Any clues on how to make this work.

Comment: there are no similar feature requests out there (for phpstorm). Looks like this won't work out of the box. I would suggest to submit this as a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes if you're interested in implementing this in future.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the tests using `artisan dusk`, make sure that the `APP_ENV` setting you are running Dusk in matches the `.env.dusk.[environment]` setting.

The Dusk browser instance always use the current .env file so...

From the [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/dusk#environment-handling) docs:

> When running tests, Dusk will back-up your .env file and rename your Dusk environment to .env. Once the tests have completed, your .env file will be restored.

If you're not running the `artisan dusk` command to run your Dusk tests, I suspect that you would have to do something similar to this code before and after running the test suite:
https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/2.0/src/Console/DuskCommand.php#L136

If you get this working I'd be very interested in how you did it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this article that works well and describes what the issue is.

https://harings.be/running-laravel-dusk-tests-from-phpstorm-atf2v

**tests/DuskTestCase.php**

```
tests/DuskTestCase.php

<?php

namespace Tests;

use Dotenv\Dotenv;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Laravel\Dusk\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;

abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
      use CreatesApplication;
    use DatabaseMigrations;

        public static function basePath($path = '')
    {
        return __DIR__ . '/../' . ($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $path : $path);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare for Dusk test execution.
     *
     * @beforeClass
     * @return void
     */
    public static function prepare()
    {
        static::startChromeDriver();
    }

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        copy(self::basePath('.env'), self::basePath('.env.backup'));
        copy(self::basePath('.env.dusk.local'), self::basePath('.env'));
        (new Dotenv(self::basePath()))->overload();

        parent::setUpBeforeClass();
    }

    public static function tearDownAfterClass(): void
    {
        copy(self::basePath('.env.backup'), self::basePath('.env'));
        unlink(self::basePath('.env.backup'));
        (new Dotenv(self::basePath()))->overload();

        parent::tearDownAfterClass();
    }

    /**
     * Create the RemoteWebDriver instance.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
            '--window-size=1920,1080',
        ]);

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
            ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
        )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an issue for that which includes a slightly improved code for `Dotenv`: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/883

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to DuskTestCase.php something like this:

```
 /**
 * @beforeClass
 * @return void
 */
public static function prepare()
{
    //static::startChromeDriver();
    copy(base_path('.env'), base_path('.env.backup'));
    copy(base_path('.env.dusk.local'), base_path('.env'));
    (new Dotenv(base_path()))->overload();
}

 /**
 * @afterClass
 * @return void
 */
public static function finish()
{
    copy(base_path('.env.backup'), base_path('.env'));
    unlink(base_path('.env.backup'));
    (new Dotenv(base_path()))->overload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx Andriy, I improved your code, this works for me :

```
use Dotenv\Dotenv;

public static function basePath($path = '') {
  return __DIR__. '/../' . ($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path : $path);
}

/**
 * Prepare for Dusk test execution.
 *
 * @beforeClass
 * @return void
 */
public static function prepare()
{
  copy(DuskTestCase::basePath('.env'), DuskTestCase::basePath('.env.backup'));
  copy(DuskTestCase::basePath('.env.dusk.local'), DuskTestCase::basePath('.env'));
  (new Dotenv(DuskTestCase::basePath()))->overload();

  static::startChromeDriver();
}

public static function closeAll()
{
  copy(DuskTestCase::basePath('.env.backup'), DuskTestCase::basePath('.env'));
  unlink(DuskTestCase::basePath('.env.backup'));
  (new Dotenv(DuskTestCase::basePath()))->overload();

  return parent::closeAll();
}
```

..since base_path() and finish() weren't working in this DuskTestCase class

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```php
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Dotenv\Dotenv;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Laravel\Dusk\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    public static function basePath($path = '') {
        return __DIR__. '/../' . ($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path : $path);
    }

    // [ ... ]

    public static function setUpBeforeClass(): void
    {
        if (file_get_contents(self::basePath('.env')) !== file_get_contents(self::basePath('.env.dusk.local'))) {
            copy(self::basePath('.env'), self::basePath('.env.backup'));
        }
        copy(self::basePath('.env.dusk.local'), self::basePath('.env'));
        Dotenv::createMutable(self::basePath())->load();

        parent::setUpBeforeClass();
    }

    public static function tearDownAfterClass(): void
    {
        copy(self::basePath('.env.backup'), self::basePath('.env'));
        unlink(self::basePath('.env.backup'));
        Dotenv::createMutable(self::basePath())->load();

        parent::tearDownAfterClass();
    }

    // [ ... ] 
}
```

Found it at https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/883